# Lookup table from another table and create a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use SQL Server something like lookup table in Excel.

I cannot normalize it since original table has over 8 million rows. It crushed my laptop when I tried it.

How can I put data into relevant columns and create a new column if data is not found.

For example)

tableA,

```
Type1        Type2
---------------------
 A            F         
 B            G
 C            H
 D            I
 E           NULL
```

TableB

```
ID     Country     AllTypes            
---------------------------------
1       Italy      A, B, C
2       USA        D, E, A, F   
4       Japan      I, O, Z        
5       UK         NULL
```

By using these two tables, I would like to get the output such as

```
ID     Country     AllTypes          Type1        Type2    UnCaptured            
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Italy      A, B, C           A, B, C       NULL     NULL
2       USA        D, E, G, F        D, E          G, F     NULL
4       Japan      I, O, Z           NULL          I        O, Z
5       UK         NULL              NULL          NULL     NULL
```

========================= Thanks to answers before I edited my question, I could do it here so far

```
with TableA as (
  select 'A' as Type1, 'F' as Type2 union all
  select 'B', 'G' union all
  select 'C', 'H' union all
  select 'D', 'I' union all
  select 'E', NULL
),
TableB as (
  select 1 as ID, 'Italy' as Country, 'A, B, C' as Alltypes union all
  select 2, 'USA', 'D, E, A, F' union all  
  select 4, 'Japan', 'I', 'O', 'Z' union all
  select 5, 'UK', NULL
)

select b.Id, b.Country, b.Alltypes,
    String_Agg(v.type1,',') Type1,
    String_Agg(v.type2,',') Type2,
    String_Agg(v.Type3,',') Uncaptured
    
from tableb b
outer apply (
    select Trim(value) t,
        case when exists 
          (select * from tablea a where a.type1=Trim(value)) 
        then Trim(value) end type1,
        case when exists
          (select * from tablea a where a.type2=Trim(value)) 
        then Trim(value) end Type2,
        Case when not exists
          ( (select * from tablea a where a.type1=Trim(value)) 
             and
             (select * from tablea a where a.type2=Trim(value))
          ) then Trim(value) end Type3
    from String_Split(alltypes, ',')
)v
group by Id, Country, AllTypes
```

But it shows error. I was also thinking of `else` but did not work as well.

Could you help me please?

Comment: TableB is not normalized, and doesn't reach 1NF.

Comment: Unless you have to work with something that already has this structure, the model is horrible to work with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple delimited values in a single column is always going to be problematic, one way is to use a combination of `string_split` and `string_agg` if you are using SQL Server 2017+

```
select b.Id, b.Country, b.Alltypes,
    String_Agg(v.type1,',') Type1,
    String_Agg(v.type2,',') Type2
from tableb b
outer apply (
    select Trim(value) t,
        case when exists 
          (select * from tablea a where a.type1=Trim(value)) 
        then Trim(value) end type1,
        case when exists
          (select * from tablea a where a.type2=Trim(value)) 
        then Trim(value) end type2
    from String_Split(alltypes, ',')
)v
group by Id, Country, AllTypes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
What should I do if I want to add one more column which is called "Uncaptured_Type"
If  there is a new Character 'O' which is neither in Type1 nor Type2

I just added 
` String_Agg(v.Uncaptured_Type',') Uncaptured_Type` 
in select and
`else Trim(value) end Uncaptured_Type`
`from String_Split(alltypes,',')` in outer apply
but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Any chance you can refactor the DB?
I would suggest

```
tableA
col1 Type
A     1
B     1
..
F     2
G     2

Country
id  Name
1   Italy      
2   USA 

Country_TableA
countryId  aId
1      A
1      B
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented previously, combining `string_split` and `string_agg` allows you to reach what you want. This is my (shorter) version:

```
select
  b.ID, b.Country, b.Alltypes, 
  string_agg(a.Type1, ',') as Type1,
  string_agg(aa.Type2, ',') as  Type2
from TableB b
  outer apply string_split(b.Alltypes, ',')
  left join TableA a
    on a.Type1 = ltrim(rtrim(value))
  left join TableA aa
    on aa.Type2 = ltrim(rtrim(value))    
group by b.ID, b.Country, b.Alltypes
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc2b1777048910e972a4706e92c1637a)

Comment: Thank you. What should I do if I want to add one more column which is called uncaptured. If there is a type which is neither in Type1 nor Type2, then it goes to uncaptured column.
It should create a new column
[I tried it like this but does not work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f3b87de673b69b874f683fa7a94f4600)